# (Qt 5.6) Program cannot find .txt file when switching to "Release" mode

Tags: c++, qt, release-mode, qt5.6

I have coding in **IDE: Qt Creator 5.6** *(Open source)*.

In my program, I have to read a `.txt` file due to run. This `.txt` file is located in my `Build` folder. The `.txt` path is: "./config/values/Login.txt".

When I run in `Debug` mode everything is fine. However, when I change to `Release` mode, my program compiles, run, and give me an `error` for not finding `Login.txt`.

Why, when `building` is done in release mode, my `release build` is empty?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What IDE? What happens if you compile your application in release mode and then run it manually instead of clicking a button in your IDE?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier.

Comment: ***Why, when building is done in release mode, my release build is empty?*** I would bet that the default folder in the release configuration is different so that when you use a relative path it is not found. Print the location of the current folder at the start of the program to debug.

Comment: Took to long to read this but indeed you are correct good sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is: I am stupid!

My early version of the project used to be located in `C:/André/Qt/`. Due to other problems I changed the name of the folder to Andr**e**. Which means that when i ran the project in another mode (with default project settings), Qt created a folder called `André` again and saved the build in there.

After I changed the settings it worked just fine.

living and learning.

I apologize for taking everybody time with this amateur mistake.